# HTTPS Connection

Tags: java-me

I am making an application which has j2me in client side and dotnet on server side.
I need to make an https connection to post to and fetch data from the server.
Can anyone help?
I tried searching on the net but i cannot find much on internet about establishing https connection.
Can anyone explain or reccommend a website??

Comment: hello @pujakhemka, did you succeed with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had problems finding J2ME HTTPS examples, [this](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/https/) is a nice article.

The above link doesn't work any more. Alternative articles:

[IBM Developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/wi-jio/)

Comment: thats just the kind of thing i was looking for.
thankx a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes of https not working is because the server does not have a valid certificate. Try catching exceptions in the part where you make the connection.

Comment: tried that...IO Exception is being thrown.It seems the certificate is not being recognised.